# I'am having segmentation fault and i don't understand why

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

As the title says. I don't Understand why this code gives me segfault!

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void cp(char s[], char d[]);
int main () {
    char s[100] = "hi there how are you";
    char d[100];
    cp(s, d);
    printf("%s\n++++++++\n%s\n", s, d);
    return 0;
}

void cp(char s[], char d[]) {
    int i, p = 0;
    while (s[i] != '\0') {
        d[i] = s[i];
        ++i;
        ++p;
    }
}
```

I know the cp implementation is terrible! I wrote it like this just for fun, then the segfault happened.

Comment: You didn't put a null terminator in `d`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line of code:

```
int i, p = 0;
```

you only initialize `p`, variable `i` is uninitialized, reading from it leads to UB.

Proper loop could be written like this:

```
for( size_t i = 0; ( d[i] = s[i] ) != 0; ++i );
```

(it will also copy null-terminator which you would be missing if initialize `i` properly)

Another variant is classical C way:

```
void cp(const char *s, char *d) 
{
    while( *d++ = *s++ );
}
```

but usually in C target is the first parameter, not the second (for example `strcpy()`)

Comment: Typo: `==` instead of `=`.

Comment: @FiddlingBits It is not typo, its intentional, that line is whole loop. Edited to make that obvious and avoid possible compiler warning

Comment: Okay, I get it now.  When `s[i] == 0` it ends.

Comment: Some might argue about `for( size_t i = 0; ( s[i] = d[i] ) != 0; ++i );` being a *proper loop*.

Comment: @PaulEvans what is wrong with it? (despite I assigned to `s` instead of `d`)

Comment: @ShinobiSan Well right of the bat the person you're showing it to misunderstood it. And it's bad to combine assignment and a boolean expression.  Hard for anyone to read and reason about. And a `for` loop having no body is also hard to read, what if the subsequent line gets indented and is read as the body? Or is indented because someone thinks it's the body?

Comment: I agree with @PaulEvans.  For an empty body I'd at least add `continue` so that my intention is clear.

Comment: @FiddlingBits that's a matter of taste

Comment: @SlavasupportsMonica It's a matter of readability not taste.  The number one reason it's bad is exactly what happened right off the bat -- someone thinking you meant `==` instead of assignment. Languages have banned it for this reason.

Comment: @PaulEvans readability is quite subjective. I found this code readable and I added condition to make it obvious. In current version its quite difficult not to see intention of assignment there.

Comment: @SlavasupportsMonica Readability is all about making it easier for *most people to read*. It's not about: I can read it so therefore it's readable. It's not subjective at all if it truly is readable.

Comment: Speaking about decisions that language designers (*eg* Python) have made and why they made them.

Comment: @PaulEvans we are talking about C here, not python. Such code is quite common for C and should be readable for any seasoned C developer. I do not think you have to write code in C readable for python developers. (disclaimer I do not have anything against python or python developers).

Answer (score 1):

You copy only while:

```
while (s[i] != '\0')
```

so `'\0'` isn't copied so when you run:

```
 printf("%s\n++++++++\n%s\n", s, d);
```

you get a segfault.

Also `i` is uninitialised:

```
int i, p = 0;
```

using separate lines avoids this typo:

```
int i = 0;
int p = 0;
```

an uninitialised `i` can blow up:

```
d[i] = s[i];
```

causing a segfault.